# Type hinting in Pycharm for dynamically generated classes

Tags: python, types, dynamic, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I'm trying to get Pycharm's linter to stop complaining when I use a dynamically created class via the Python `type( )` function.  A simplified version of the actual code looks like the following.

Yes, it's weird to be working with the class object like that, but in the real code, it makes sense (SQLAlchemy ORM classes, if you're curious).  Note the final line which points out the Pycharm warning.

```
class MyClass(object):
    ID_NUM: int = 0

    def __init__(self, id_num: int, first_name: str, last_name: str):
        self.ID_NUM = id_num
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name


def make_augmented_class(cls):
    def augmented__eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.id_num == other.id_num
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    new_cls = type('{}Augmented'.format(cls.__name__), tuple([cls]), {})
    new_cls.__eq__ = augmented__eq__
    return new_cls


def do_stuff(my_class):
    print(my_class.ID_NUM)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_stuff(MyClass)

    augmented_class = make_augmented_class(MyClass)
    do_stuff(augmented_class)  # <=== PYCHARM CODE LINTER COMPLAINS THAT "Type 'type' doesn't have expected attribute 'ID_NUM'"
```

I've tried a couple of type hints for the `do_stuff( )` function, such as `def do_stuff(my_class: type):` and `def do_stuff(my_class: MyClass):`, but that just causes different linter warnings.

The code works, but I'd like to eliminate the linter warnings somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good reason to use the `type` function to create a class for your use case. Instead, simply create the new class in the closure of the function and return the class object so that the linter can more easily infer that the new class is a subclass of the given class. That said, I found that you would still need to type hint the argument and the returning value of the function in order for PyCharm not to complain:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def make_augmented_class(cls: type[T]) -> type[T]:
    class _AugmentingWrapper(cls):
        def __eq__(self, other):
            try:
                return self.ID_NUM == other.ID_NUM
            except AttributeError:
                return False
    return _AugmentingWrapper
```

Comment: That's really elegant!  Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, Pycharm still complains that "Expected type 'MyClass', got 'Type[MyClass]' instead" for calling the `do_stuff( )` function.  If I change the return type hint on `make_augmented_class` to just "`T`" instead of "`type[T]`" Pycharm is happy.  Thanks!

Comment: Got it-- updating question now...

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm isn't quite able to deal with dynamically constructed classes (quite understandably, such dynamic systems are hard or impossible to analyze).

You can however annotated `make_augmented_class` to silence this warning, and use a small `cast` to tell PyCharm to trust you:

```
def make_augmented_class(cls: type[T]) -> type[T]:
    def augmented__eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.id_num == other.id_num
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    new_cls = type('{}Augmented'.format(cls.__name__), tuple([cls]), {})
    new_cls.__eq__ = augmented__eq__
    return cast(type[T], new_cls)
```

(Interestingly, mypy complains about the assignment to `__eq__` which PyCharm doesn't. <strike>However, I believe mypy is just wrong here</strike> [see GH issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2427), so silencing that line with `type: ignore` is a decent course of action. Or you could move it into the third parameter of `type`)

Comment: That's nice and simple.  You and @blhsing suggested very similar solutions.  Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in a reply to blhsing above, Pycharm still complains that "Expected type 'MyClass', got 'Type[MyClass]' instead" for calling the `do_stuff( )` function.  If I change the return type hint on `make_augmented_class` to just "`T`" instead of "`type[T]`" Pycharm is happy.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah-- got it now.  I'll update my question.

Comment: @RoyWood Please don't fundamentally change the question after you got answers.

Comment: Sorry!  I left the original question as-is and then added a clearly-labeled final solution.  The answers didn't quite work, so it was necessary to tweak them slightly for something that does work.  I wanted to leave a full, working solution for anyone who later ran into the same problem...

Comment: @RoyWood Please don't add solutions to questions. See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)